# Make card transaction after validation

Tags: jquery, validation, transactions, payment

I am currently working on a website of which has to allow recurring payments. 
I have been working with different card transaction services before, but this time I was thingking of using a credit card validator. But I am a bit confused as to how you would actually make the end transaction, once you have validated the customers credit card and made sure it is legit. Would I have to use a second card transaction method like Stripe, or are there services made, of which you have to implement and then they make the recurring transactions after the validation?
I know this isn't exactly a coding question, but I wasn't able to find any real information on what happens between the validation and the transaction.

For the validation I would be using one of the many jquery validator plugins available.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot validate a credit-card on the client-side using Javascript. You must implement server-side credit card validation, as fake credit cards that PASS client-side validation can be generated by abusing the [Luhn algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Luhn_algorithm).

I recommend Stripe. Stripe will make a verification charge to the card (that isn't actually taken out of their account, just to make sure it exists and has money in it) in order to validate it.

Comment: I appreciate the feedback, with what you are saying, does that mean a credit card validator like http://jquerycreditcardvalidator.com/ isn't really going to help?

Comment: Yes. That is worthless in my opinion. It actually uses a Luhn checksum to test it, which I mentioned doesn't work as they can be faked. If you want to verify that the credit card is real and chargable you'll have to use a different, server-side, solution.

Comment: Alright I see, but let's say I were to take the risk and use the jquery validator. Do you know how I would then make the actual transaction?

Comment: https://stripe.com/